# How to Pass a List as an Argument in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a list of users in Dart, but I don't know how to pass the list as an argument.

```dart
List<User> user = [
  User(
      username: 'Muhammad Wajahat',
      desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectaur.'),
  User(
      username: 'Muhammad Ali', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectaur.'),
  User(
      username: 'Masab Mehmood',
      desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectaur.'),
  User(username: 'Faiq Tanveer', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectaur.')
];
```

I've tried this but this doesn't work:

```dart
card(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void someFunction(List<User> users) {
  // do something
}
```

And calling the function:

```
someFunction(users) ;
```

--

EDIT: Okay, it is specifically about a Card.

Well, depends ... if you want to somehow put all user information on one card ... But I **assume** you want to create a bunch of cards, one for each user?

There is a number of ways to reach that. This is one of the easiest:

```
for (var user in users)
  Card(
    child: Text('Name: ${user.name}'),
  ),
```

Comment: Hope my edit is better than my first try. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Type Inference let you send any type of data in functin
Create method like this:

```
void card(var users) {
  // Do whatever you want to do with list 
}
```

and you can call this card method where you want like this:

```
card(user)
```

and you will be done.